# Is there a step-by-step process for converting a series of pipelines into a functional composition?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Is there a step-by-step process for converting several pipelines into a functional composition?

**Side note:**
*Did I even use the term "functional composition" in the right context?*

**I have the following code:**

```
let purchase qty inventory =
    buyFrom inventory qty |> fromInventory
                          |> reduceBy qty
```

I wanted to refactor this code to support functional composition.

**So I thought I could do this:**

```
let purchase qty inventory =
    buyFrom inventory >> fromInventory >> reduceBy qty
```

This code compiles. However, it appears that I am missing an argument when attempting to invoke the purchase function within the debugger.

**Here's my test for the function:**

```
[<Test>]
let ``buy last product``() =
    [SomeProduct] |> purchase 1
                  |> should equal []
```

**NOTE:**

I'm still struggling with FP fundamentals and still do not understand the process of converting a pipeline work flow into a functional composition.

I think I understand that functional composition relies on partial application which I think I have a handle on now. Thus, I have reason to believe that my refactored function is missing an argument.

Any guidance on a workflow I can use to get better at functional composition?

**Appendix:**

```
type Product =
    | SomeProduct

type TransactionResult = { Price:decimal; Inventory:Product list }

(* Functions *)

let priceOf qty product =
    match product with
    | SomeProduct -> match qty with
                     | 3 -> decimal (qty - 1) * 1.99m
                     | _ -> decimal (qty) * 1.99m

let rec reduceBy count list =
    match list with
    | first::remaining when count = 1         -> remaining
    | first::second::remaining when count > 1 -> second::remaining |> reduceBy (count - 1)
    | remaining when count = 0                -> remaining
    | _ -> []

let buyFrom inventory qty =
    { Price=priceOf qty (List.head inventory); Inventory=inventory }

let fromInventory transactionResult =
    transactionResult.Inventory
```

Comment: The normal thing would be `let f a = a |> b |> c` becomes `let f = b >> c`.  The example will be hard because of the reuse of qty

Comment: I take it that in the statement `Any guidance on a workflow I can use to get better at functional composition?` that you did not mean workflow as in [Computation Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/computation-expressions-%5Bfsharp%5D)? I am just noting it because you are learning and want to make sure you are on the right track with the vocabulary.

Comment: I meant workflow as in a list of steps to accomplish a task.

Answer (score 7):

The direct translation to a composed form would be either:

Using "forward" function composition:

```
let purchase qty inventory = (buyFrom inventory >> fromInventory >> reduceBy qty) qty
```

Using "backward" function composition (Personally, I'm not sure I like the term "backward" because this is function composition in the traditional mathemetical sense of the term, i.e. `f << g = f ∘ g`):

```
let purchase' qty inventory = reduceBy qty << fromInventory << buyFrom inventory <| qty
```

As you can perhaps see from the above examples, it's really most valuable when it lets you skip the last argument entirely.  In this example, you can't do that because you depend on `qty` twice so I'd recommend you stick with piping here.

---

In general, if you have a function `f(x)` and a function `g(x)` you can write a composed function `h(x) = (f ∘ g)(x)` in the following ways:

```
let h x = f (g (x))
let h x = x |> g |> f
let h x = f << g <| x
let h x = (g >> f) x
```

In the second two cases, using function composition, you can omit the `x` entirely.

```
let h = f << g
let h = g >> f
```

Comment: Waiting for a tie breaking vote so that I can select an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Usually, if you can massage your pipeline expression to have the form

```
let f x y value = value |> f1 x |> f2 y |> f3
```

you can refactor it to

```
let f x y = f1 x >> f2 y >> f3
```

That's not quite the case here, as your expression begins with a function call (`buyFrom inventory qty`), the value of which is then piped to `fromInventory`.

In this case, I think you can refactor to

```
let purchase' inventory qty =
    qty |> buyFrom inventory |> fromInventory |> reduceBy qty
```

but then you can't really get any further because `qty` is also needed as an argument to `reduceBy`.

I *think* you might be able to eliminate both occurrences of `qty` by using the Reader or State monad, but it's hardly worth the effort.

Comment: Waiting for a tie breaking vote so that I can select an answer.

Comment: @ScottNimrod Pick the one you found most helpful personally -- there's a reason only you can mark it accepted